# Can I hide the text of the Sign In with Apple button? (a.k.a ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton)?

Tags: ios, swiftui, sign-in-with-apple, custom-button

I am implementing Sign In with Apple on my iOS app (SwiftUI).

In SwiftUI, I can use the 'SignInWithAppleButton' (https://morioh.com/p/524e0408008c), this button displays the Apple logo and a text that can be "Sign In with Apple", "Sign Up with Apple" or "Continue with Apple" depending on the button type chosen (ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton.ButtonType).

However, I would like the button to be sized 120x60 (WxH). If I just resize this button, the text is still visible and displayed very small, the Apple icon is also resized and cannot be seen, so it is not useable. I want to show **only the Apple icon**. It seems allowed by the design guidelines (https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sign-in-with-apple/overview/buttons/)

How can I do this in SwiftUI? I could not find examples of custom Sign in with Apple buttons implementations.

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: can you show your tried code

Comment: You will need to download the provided Apple icon resources from the page you linked to and use it to create your own custom button

Comment: The code i tried is exactly the one of this blog: https://morioh.com/p/524e0408008c

Comment: @Paulw11 that's what I want to do, but how do I link this custom button to the sign in functions? I couldn't find this example in the doc or on the web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to customize behavior/looks you will have to create your own. I suggest you start with the `init()` for `SignInWithAppleButton`

```
init(SignInWithAppleButton.Label, onRequest: (ASAuthorizationAppleIDRequest) -> Void, onCompletion: ((Result<ASAuthorization, Error>) -> Void))
```

Then make a `View` and a `ViewModel:  ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate` that uses that initializer.

`onRequest` and `onCompletion` are function blocks/completion handlers so you will need to [read up on those](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/161/how-to-use-result-in-swift)

So you know how to use them when you `handleAuthorizationAppleIDButtonPress` (add to the request) and when your `ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate` returns `.success` or `.failure`

Your `View` `body` only needs a `Button` that calls the`handleAuthorizationAppleIDButtonPress()` in your `ViewModel` (See Apple's sample code)

You can find Apple's sample code in the documentation [Implementing User Authentication with Sign in with Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/implementing_user_authentication_with_sign_in_with_apple)